# Multiple update in Mongodb(pymongo) from list of dicts

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

We have some BSON documents in our database collection.

items:

```
[{"id": 0,
"programs": [
    {
      "id": 300017,
      "name": "Program A-Level (English)",
      "date": [
        "01.01.2023",
        "31.12.2023"
      ],
      "age": [
        16,
        17,
        18
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 17456,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": x,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      ],
      "living": {
        "id": 500000,
        "name": "with accommodation"
      },
      "period": "trimester"
    },
    {
      "id": 300004,
      "name": "Base school(English)",
      "date": [
        "02.09.2023",
        "20.06.2024"
      ],
      "age": [
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 12000,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": X,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      ],
      "living": {
        "id": 500000,
        "name": "with accommodation"
      },
      "period": "trimester"
    },
},
{"id": 1,
"programs": [
    {
      "id": 300017,
      "name": "Program A-Level",
      "date": [
        "01.01.2023",
        "31.12.2023"
      ],
      "age": [
        16,
        17,
        18
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 15000,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": x,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      }]
}]
```

**List of dicts for update have same structure
**

```
[{"id": 0,
"programs": [
    {
      "id": 300017,
      "name": "Program A-Level (English)",
      "date": [
        "01.01.2024",
        "31.12.2024"
      ],
      "age": [
        16,
        17,
        18
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 19000,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": x,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      ],
      "living": {
        "id": 500000,
        "name": "with accommodation"
      },
      "period": "trimester"
    },
    {
      "id": 300004,
      "name": "Base school(English)",
      "date": [
        "02.09.2024",
        "20.06.2025"
      ],
      "age": [
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 14000,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": X,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      ],
      "living": {
        "id": 500000,
        "name": "with accommodation"
      },
      "period": "trimester"
    },
},
{"id": 1,
"programs": [
    {
      "id": 300017,
      "name": "Program A-Level",
      "date": [
        "01.01.2024",
        "31.12.2024"
      ],
      "age": [
        16,
        17,
        18
      ],
      "price": [
        {
          "original_price": 17000,
          "original_currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "calc_price": x,
          "calc_currency": "USD"
        }
      }]
}]
```

Need to update all "programs" from list of dicts with same structure and ids, but with different
"program fields" how to do that?

I did not try to do anything, because I don’t understand a little how to do it for a multi-document and only for the "programs" field from list of dicts.

I understand that i can drop all in collection and add new but that is not a right way just to update part of documents.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are given _"List of dicts for update"_ that appear to be full documents, should you just [`find_one_and_replace`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_replace) each document?

Comment: Trying replacement it's deadly one theme! Just stock all script.

Comment: Looks like nothing better then just create extra collection and renew just it not whole document